# ShutdownSignalException: connection error RabbitMQ on STS4

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am attempting to connect to RabbitMQ locally on port 15672 but am getting connection error. I am unsure what could be causing this as I am attempting to learn RabbitMQ... This is tutorial 1 I can't even get running. (https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html)

Below is the code and error. The only changes from the tutorial I have made are specifying the port and username/password. Any ideas?

```
package send.java;

import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;

public class Send {
    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception{
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        factory.setPort(15672);
        factory.setUsername("guest");
        factory.setPassword("guest");
        try (Connection connection = factory.newConnection(); Channel channel = connection.createChannel()){
            channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
            String message = "Hello World!";
            channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
            System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
        }
    }

}
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:129)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:125)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:375)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:156)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1106)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1063)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1021)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1182)
    at send.java.Send.main(Send.java:15)
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:502)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:317)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:294)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:184)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:598)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Answer (score 4):

Port 15672 is the (default) HTTP port for the admin (management plugin) UI.

The default AMQP port is 5672.

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. I was using port 15672 instead of port 5672 for AMQP

Comment: That's useful info, I didn't realize that even though that's not the cause of my error. Upvoted :D